# Read records in batches from Google Cloud Datastore using Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam to read data from Google Cloud Datastore with the help of Beam's own `io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio` Python APIs.

I run my pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow.

I want to ensure that my workers are not overloaded with data.

How can I read data in batches or ensure using some other mechanism that my workers are not pulling a huge amount of data in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow automatically does this for you. By default, `datastoreio` breaks your files into 64MB chucks. If you want to break them up into smaller pieces, use the `num_splits` parameter on the initializer to specify how many pieces to break each file into.